# How to return result from ajax call synchronously

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've searched around a lot, but I just can't grasp the fundamentals of returning data from an ajax call's success method. I'm normally ruby dev, and fully understanding js/coffeescript's best practices have been a hurdle.

I have a CS file that does something like this:

```
$ ->
  $.when(Foo.load()).done (data) ->
  # manipulate data
```

But this "data" comes from either a cached object in the browser, or an ajax call's successful response. Here's some info on the `Foo` class

```
class @Foo
   _now = new Date().getTime()
   _expiration = new Date(_now).setHours(24, 0, 0, 0) #24 hours from now

  @save: (data) ->
    record = { value: JSON.stringify data, timestamp: _expiration }
    localStorage.setItem('responseData', JSON.stringify record)

  @load : ->
   record = JSON.parse localStorage.getItem('responseData')
   if record and _now < record.timestamp
     JSON.parse record.value
   else
     Foo.refresh()

  @refresh : ->
    $.ajax(
      url: '/data'
      dataType: 'JSON'
      type: 'post'
      async: false
      success: (data) ->
        Foo.save data.results
    )
    Foo.load()
```

The problem stems from the `load` and `refresh` methods. As you can see, we can result in an infinite loop. `load` calls `refresh` which will call `load` which will call `refresh` and so on.

What I am looking for is a way to return the response from the ajax method in the load() method, so it performs the same way as the `JSON.parse record.value`

```
if record and _now < record.timestamp
     JSON.parse record.value
else
  # RETURN the result of the successful ajax call, this would mean that when we call $.when(Foo.load()).done we would have waited for the ajax call to run.
```

If anyone has any tips, they would be much appreciated! I will gladly elaborate as needed.

Would the ajax call async attribute have anything to do with it? I was thinking it was the behavior of the 2 class methods in Foo

Comment: You *can't* return values from an asynchronous call. Instead, you craft your API with provisions for callback functions.

Comment: Thank you for that reference, I will take a look